# Ajax Autocomplete for jQuery without data suggestions

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have

```
var autocompleteProfessionals = that.container.find("#ProfessionalsName");

    autocompleteProfessionals.each(function () {
        $(this).autocomplete({
            serviceUrl: '../Professionals/FindProfessionals',
            minChars: 2,
            delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/,
            maxHeight: 200,
            width: 400,
            zIndex: 9999,
            deferRequestBy: 100,  
            onSelect: function (value, data) {
                that.container.find("#IdProfessionals").val(data.IdProfessionals);

            }
        });
    }
    );
```

When I find professionals with autocomplete and select him, I set his Id. Then I delete this professional name from field and enter professional name that does not exist. 
I have here problem, because IdProfessionals is valid, but ProfessionalsName is not.

How to delete value from IdProfessionals when I delete Professional name from text field?

Comment: I added `autocompleteProfessionals.keyup(function () {
            if ($(this).val() === "") {   
                that.container.find("#IdProfessionals").val(-1);
            } 
        });` if someone has better idea, tell me.

Answer (score 0):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-search

```
var autocompleteProfessionals = that.container.find("#ProfessionalsName");

autocompleteProfessionals.autocomplete({
   serviceUrl: '../Professionals/FindProfessionals',
   minChars: 2,
   delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/,
   maxHeight: 200,
   width: 400,
   zIndex: 9999,
   deferRequestBy: 100,  
   onSelect: function (value, data) {
     that.container.find("#IdProfessionals").val(data.IdProfessionals);
   }
   search: function(event, ui) {
     $('#IdProfessionals').val('');
   } 
 });
```

Comment: Mine autocomplete you can find here [link](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/)

Comment: I looked at the source code and the plugin you use doesn't seem to support this. You can either look for an alternative (The link I pasted is industry quality) or contact that plugin's owner.

Comment: I have a lot of place in my project with this autocomplete. Is there another solution with this plagin?